# FastAPI python: How to run a thread in the background?

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi, background-task, uvicorn

I'm making a server in python using FastAPI, and I want a function that is not related to my API, to run in background every 5 minutes (like checking stuff from an API and printing stuff depending on the response)

I've tried to make a thread that runs the function `start_worker`, but it doesn't print anything.

Does anyone know how to do so ?

```py
def start_worker():
    print('[main]: starting worker...')
    my_worker = worker.Worker()
    my_worker.working_loop() # this function prints "hello" every 5 seconds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('[main]: starting...')
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
    _worker_thread = Thread(target=start_worker, daemon=False)
    _worker_thread.start()
```

Comment: Try moving the thread stuff to before the run().  It's possible the run() doesn't return until the server dies.

Comment: doesn't work as well, it doesn't even print('[main]: starting...'), but the api is working

Comment: The solution I found was to create an endpoint for background work. The endpoint is hit with a CRON job. The upside of using an endpoint is that you can have the code running with async/await functions including a database.

I used the "background.add_task" function to launch the background job and return an ok immediately to the CRON request.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Option 1

You should start your Thread before calling `uvicorn.run`, as `uvicorn.run` is blocking the thread.

```
import time
import threading
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
class BackgroundTasks(threading.Thread):
    def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
        while True:
            print('Hello')
            time.sleep(5)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = BackgroundTasks()
    t.start()
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

You could also start your thread using FastAPI's [startup event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event), as long as it is ok to run before the application starts.

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    t = BackgroundTasks()
    t.start()
```

### Option 2

You could instead use a repeating [Event scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) for the background task, as below:

```
import sched, time
from threading import Thread
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_event(sc): 
    print("Hello")
    sc.enter(5, 1, print_event, (sc,))

def start_scheduler():
    s.enter(5, 1, print_event, (s,))
    s.run()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    thread = Thread(target = start_scheduler)
    thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

### Option 3

If your task is an `async def` function (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on `def` vs `async def` endpoints/background tasks in FastAPI), then you could add the task to the current [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), using the [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) function. The `create_task()` function takes a coroutine object (i.e., an `async def` function) and returns a [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) object (which can be used to `await` the task, if needed, or `cancel` it , etc). The call creates the task inside the event loop for the current thread, and executes it in the "background" concurrently with all other tasks in the event loop, switching between them at `await` points.

It is required to have an event loop created before calling `create_task()`, and this is already created when starting the `uvicorn` server either programmatically (using, for instance, `uvicorn.run(app)`) or in the terminal (using, for instance, `uvicorn app:app`). Instead of using `asyncio.create_task()`, one could also use [`asyncio.get_running_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop) to get the current event `loop`, and then call [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task).

The example below uses the recently documented way for adding `lifespan` events (using a context manager), i.e., code that should be executed before the application starts up, as well as when the application is shutting down (see the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77308268/17865804) for more details and examples). One could also still use the `startup` and `shutdown` events, as demonstrated in the previous options; however, those event handlers might be removed from future FastAPI/Starlette versions.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import asyncio


async def print_task(s): 
    while True:
        print('Hello')
        await asyncio.sleep(s)

        
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Run at startup
    asyncio.create_task(print_task(5))
    yield
    # Run on shutdown (if required)
    print('Shutting down...')


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
```

Comment: How resilient is the subprocess? Is it possible for the BackgroundTasks service to be killed, and if so, does FastAPI's event handler restart it automatically?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: @DM You should opt going for the third option, if possible, as in that case, your task would run in the event loop, which runs in the main thread, while in the first two options, a separate thread would have to be created for running the task. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on *asynchronous* programming and how FastAPI works under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

@Chris's solution works correctly!

However, if you want to improve it and remove the redundant `start_scheduler` method, you just need to pass the `sc` argument directly to the `print_event` method with `kwargs` param as below:

```
import sched
import time
from threading import Thread

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


def print_event(sc=None): 
    print("Hello")
    sc.enter(5, 1, print_event, (sc,))
    sc.run()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    thread = Thread(target=print_event, kwargs=dict(sc=s))
    thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: Now deprecated, but easy to replace with lifespan https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/