# Running separate infinite background thread in a python webapp (fastapi/flask/django)

Tags: python, fastapi, wsgi, uvicorn, django-wsgi

How can i launch an application which does below 2 things:

1. Expose rest endpoint via FastAPI.
2. Run a seperate thread **infintely** (rabbitmq consumer - [pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) waiting for request.

Below is the code through which i am launching the fastAPI server. But when i try to run a thread,  before execution of below line, it says *coroutine was never awaited.*

[image]

How can both be run parallely?

Comment: The error you are seeing is because you are not awaiting a `coroutine`

Comment: The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872276/fastapi-python-how-to-run-a-thread-in-the-background/70873984#70873984 is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for.
There is a library called celery that makes multithreading easy to manage in python.

Check it out:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


def run(corofn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        coro = corofn(*args)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    finally:
        loop.close()


async def sleep_forever():
    await asyncio.sleep(1000)


#
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, run, sleep_forever),
               loop.run_in_executor(executor, run, uvicorn.run, app)]
    print(await asyncio.gather(*futures))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

*Note: This may hinder your FastAPI performance. Better approach would be to use a Celery Task*