# Unable to send json request when using fastapi

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, fastapi

I have error in the following code when I try to send a request with json data in it, is it because it only works synchronously, so does not work in fastapi which work asynchronously? If that is the case, what is the simplest way to send a request with json data in it?

```
import time
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, BackgroundTasks
import multiprocessing as mp
import uvicorn
import requests
import json

def printmessage(job):    
    time.sleep(5) 
    print(job)
   

if __name__ == 'webhook_fastapi':  
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/webhook'
    data = { 'text': 'hello'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    print("Request Sent!")

app = FastAPI()  
@app.post("/webhook")
async def webhook(request : Request, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):              
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVED")  
    job="doctor"  
    background_tasks.add_task(printmessage,job)     
    print('done')   
    return 'WEBHOOK RECEIVED'


if __name__ == '__main__':     
    print("PROGRAM LAUNCH...")
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...") 
    background_tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    job="doctor"
    background_tasks.add_task(printmessage,job) 

    uvicorn.run("webhook_fastapi:app", reload=False)
```

OUTPUT:

```
__main__
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
webhook_fastapi
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 169, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
> line 96, in create_connection
> raise err   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
> line 86, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 699, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 394, in _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 234, in request
> super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py",
> line 1279, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py",
> line 1325, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py",
> line 1274, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py",
> line 1034, in _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py",
> line 974, in send
> self.connect()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 200, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 181, in _new_conn
> raise NewConnectionError( urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000013C0E494310>:
> Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 439, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 755, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
> line 574, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1',
> port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhook (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x0000013C0E494310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users***\webhook_fastapi.py", line 40, in 
> uvicorn.run("webhook_fastapi:app", reload=False)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py",
> line 463, in run
> server.run()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py",
> line 60, in run
> return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py",
> line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 642, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py",
> line 67, in serve
> config.load()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py",
> line 458, in load
> self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py",
> line 21, in import_from_string
> module = importlib.import_module(module_str)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib_*init*_.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 850, in
> exec_module   File "", line 228, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "c:\Users***\webhook_fastapi.py", line 19, in 
> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 117, in post
> return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 542, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 655, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 516, in send
> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /webhook (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x0000013C0E494310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it')) PS C:\Users***>

Answer (score 0):

There is no server running when you're trying to make your request. `uvicorn` is importing your code, and you're apparently trying to make a request *while the code is being imported*.

uvicorn can't launch the API and bind to the port before it has finished importing the code and the ASGI application has been set up and properly configured.

Comment: I tried to move the request code after the line of uvicorn, but the result is the same and it appears the server has not fully launched yet.. any recommend solution such that I can send a request back to my own fastapi server?

Comment: That won't help, since the server won't have launched until after all the code has been parsed/imported/run. The question then usually becomes: why would you want to do that? What is the reason for having to make a request, instead of configuring whatever state you want internally as part of your application setup?

Comment: I intend to run a function after the fastapi server start running for my own initialization of my program.. and the only way I can think of is to generate a request webhook for my server to receive it.. any smarter or direct solution?

Comment: You can use the events provided by FastAPI: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/ - `@app.on_event("startup")`

Comment: yes, i considered that but the server is not launched yet by that time, is it possible to trigger a function after the server is successfully launched? (because i want to utilise the background task function as well)

Comment: @Jimmy You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804) helpful.

Comment: yes, it appears that threading allow me to wait for the server to start and run a request function with background task