# FastAPI: perform an action at a specific time

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scheduled-tasks, fastapi

I work on a system, that reminds the user about some action with an alarm.

I need to make it work by triggering some functions that select data from a database (PostgreSQL) and notify the user via FCM.

The easiest solution is to make a repeatable task, with a minimal interval, but I need to notify at the **exact** time, not before and not after it.

How can I do it, if the reminder datetime is stored in the database and reminders can be repeatable (store type of repeat and interval. Without next datetime)?

The `Reminder` model is the following:

```
class Reminder(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'reminders'


    ...
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    last_reminded_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    repeat_end_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)  # None - infinite.
    category = Column(Enum(ReminderCategoryEnum), nullable=False)
    repeat_type = Column(
        Enum(ReminderRepeatTypeEnum),
        default=ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER,
        server_default=ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER.name,
        nullable=False,
    )
    repeat_interval = Column(RelativeInterval(native=True), nullable=False)  # Interval
    is_finished = Column(Boolean, default=False, server_default=false(), nullable=False)
    is_notified = Column(Boolean, default=False, server_default=false(), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # noqa: D107
        repeat_type: Optional[ReminderRepeatTypeEnum] = kwargs.get('repeat_type')
        if 'repeat_interval' not in kwargs:
            if not repeat_type:
                repeat_type = ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER
            self.repeat_interval = repeat_type.timedelta
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def previous_date(self) -> Optional[datetime.datetime]:
        ...

    @property
    def next_date(self) -> Optional[datetime.datetime]:
        ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI python: How to run a thread in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872276/fastapi-python-how-to-run-a-thread-in-the-background)

Comment: @Chris I guess, not. I'll use fastapi background tasks with wait until needed date and notify user, then wait until next date

Comment: Did you check Option 3 (in the link above) out?

Comment: @Chris yes. Unfortunately, my task is not async. My question was not about how to make my task work in background. I needed something like dynamic scheduler, that trigger some function, that notify user in some user-specified times (this time stores in database). I don't want to make a lot of queries.

Comment: I used `apscheduler` to manage background tasks and created task, that start at specific time and perform notification. Here is [my implementation of task recreate on server start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76102199/recreate-background-tasks-on-server-restart?noredirect=1#comment134214547_76102199).

Comment: Using `apscheduler` was one of the solutions I was about to post here. Glad you got it resolved. I'll still try to post an answer though, once I get the chance, with all the available solutions, as this would help future readers. So please leave the question open

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your answers. Sure, I' won't close question.

Answer (score 0):

We can implement a solution that leverages [Redis Keyspace Notifications](https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/), which is a Pub/Sub for events affecting Redis data.

**Solution Overview**

- When an Insert/Update event occurs on the `Reminder` table, a key is added to Redis with all the relevant info (ex. `Reminder` item id) and an `expiration datetime = the relevant datetime that we want the reminder alarm to set off`.
- A Keyspace Notification Subscriber will be ready to consume any EXPIRE events and send the notification to the user.
- In case of repeated notifications, the key should be added back to Redis with a new expiring date.
- In case of a `Reminder` item deletion, Redis key can be removed (not critical, we can have the check inside the Subscriber code)

**Pros:**

- Non-complicated solution based on a proven tool (Redis)
- Easy to maintain and expand
- In-time notification handling without mind-warping scheduling management.

**Cons:**

- Complicates your stack as it adds Redis.
- Need to think of connected cleanup between `Reminder` items and Redis items
- Need to learn about [Redis persistence](https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/) and think about handling outages etc.

**Let's see the parts:**

1. On `Reminder` item Insert/Update to DB, we need to calculate the expiration time in **seconds** for the first notification
2. Insert the key to redis with the previously calculated expiration_time:

   ```
   redis_conn.set(reminder_item.id, "reminder")
   redis_con.expire(reminder_item.id, expiration_time_in_seconds)
   ```

   `redis_conn` is a redis connection initiated as per the [python instructions](https://redis.io/docs/clients/python/) (*initialization example in step 4 below*)
3. Create an event handler method:

   ```
   def event_habdler(msg):
       redis_reminder_key = msg["data"].decode("utf-8")

       # Use the redis_reminder_key to retrieve the corresponding   
       # reminder item from SQL and notify the user.

       # Check if you need to delete the key or update it's expiration time  
       if <check-for-last-notification>:
           redis_conn.delete(key)
       else:
           expiration_time_in_seconds = <calculate-next-notification-time-in-seconds>
           redis_conn.expire(redis_reminder_key, expiration_time_in_seconds)
   ```
4. Initialize a Redis connection on FastAPI startup and connect a Subscriber to the Keyspace Notification using [FastAPI's startup event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event):

   ```
   import redis

   from fastapi import FastAPI

   app = FastAPI()

   @app.on_event("startup")
   async def startup_event():
       redis_conn = redis.Redis(<connection-info>)
       redis_pubsub = redis_conn.pubsub()

       redis_conn.config_set('notify-keyspace-events', 'Ex')
       pubsub.psubscribe(**{"__keyevent@0__:expired": event_handler})
       pubsub.run_in_thread(sleep_time=0.01)
   ```

**Suggestions for ease of use:**

- Create `redis_conn` in a separate file (like `settings.py`) and use it as `settings.redis_conn`
- *Optional*: Add scheduled events for data sync checks between SQL and Redis.

---

**Subscriber `event_handler` inspired from:** https://medium.com/@imamramadhanns/working-with-redis-keyspace-notifications-x-python-c5c6847368a