# How to repeatedly run a function in FastAPI, fastapi-utils repeat_every or asyncio.create_task?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

I want to repeatedly run a function in the background forever with FastAPI. I found two  solutions on Internet but I don't know which one to choose.

The follow two code are both to update `_STATUS` value and show the value on the web-page.

In my opinion:

1. the decorator `repeat_every` from `fastapi-utils` is more readable (at least for someone, like me, who does not know much about `asyncio`. However `fastapi-utils` has no recent updates. Its latest version on PyPI was released on 2020-03-07.
2. On the other hand, `asyncio` is a built-in library in Python. But I don't quite understand the code below. If my aim is to update `_STATUS` every 3 seconds, is `await asyncio.sleep(3)` necessary or just a placeholder? If the `_STATUS += 1` is replaced by some function that needs 2 seconds, shall I change it to `await asyncio.sleep(1)`? And what is the difference of the `app_startup` function between the 2 solutions? Thanks.

Overall, could you please tell me what the pros and cons of these 2 solutions? Which would one would you prefer? Thanks.

#### Based on [fastapi-utils](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/#the-repeat_every-decorator)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_utils.tasks import repeat_every

app = FastAPI()

_STATUS: int = 0


@app.on_event('startup')
@repeat_every(seconds=3)
async def app_startup():
    global _STATUS
    _STATUS += 1


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return _STATUS
```

#### Based on [asyncio.create_task](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2713) (see `insomnes` comments)

```py
import asyncio

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

_STATUS: int = 0


async def run_main():
    global _STATUS
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        _STATUS += 1


@app.on_event('startup')
async def app_startup():
    asyncio.create_task(run_main())


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return _STATUS
```

And excuse for using `_STATUS` as a global variable which is a bad habit, here is just to make the code runnable.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my aim is to update `_STATUS` every 3 seconds, is `await asyncio.sleep(3)` necessary or just a placeholder?

Without that `sleep` statement, your loop would look like this:

```
while True:
    _STATUS += 1
```

That will increment `_STATUS` *as fast as possible*. You need the `sleep` statement to delay the loop.

> If the `_STATUS += 1` is replaced by some function that needs 2 seconds, shall I change it to await asyncio.sleep(1)?

Sure, that's one way of handling it. Alternatively, you can rewrite your code so that the update happens asynchronously from the delay, like this:

```
async def do_update():
    global _STATUS
    _STATUS += 1

async def run_main():
    global _STATUS
    while True:
        asyncio.create_task(do_update())
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

@app.on_event('startup')
async def app_startup():
    asyncio.create_task(run_main())
```

This will call `do_update` every 3 seconds, regardless of how long it takes to execute. Of course, if `do_update` takes *longer* than three seconds to execute, you'll end up with two instances of this method running concurrently; there are several ways to mitigate that situation (e.g., a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock) or other synchronization primitives).

> Overall, could you please tell me what the pros and cons of these 2 solutions? Which would one would you prefer? Thanks.

If you look at the code for the [`repeat_every` decorator](https://github.com/dmontagu/fastapi-utils/blob/3ef27a6f67ac10fae6a8b4816549c0c44567a451/fastapi_utils/tasks.py#L17), you'll see that the two solutions are effectively identical.

Using a decorator is probably cleaner if you have to do the same thing at multiple points in your code, but you could just as easily implement that yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry for not being clearer. My main question is: "Overall, could you please tell me what the pros and cons of these 2 solutions? Which would one would you prefer? Thanks.". I have also added it to my question above.