# Is there a way to run other code when a FastAPI app is idle?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I want to run some Code in a FastAPI app when there is idle time (meaning no HTTP-Request is currently processed). Does FastAPI provide any solution for this or is there some way to run a FastAPI app asynchronously (awaiting uvicorn.run() doesn't work, because it blocks the event loop)?

Preferably I do not want to use threading or multiprocessing (I know that it would work with these modules).

Comment: You should be able to do this via threading. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872276/fastapi-python-how-to-run-a-thread-in-the-background

Comment: What do you want to happen _when_ a request comes in?