# fastapi @app.on_event decorator is deprecated, how can I create a simple @repeat_every task with Lifespan Events

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi

I have the following decorator that works perfectly, but fastapi says `@app.on_event("startup")` is deprecated, and I'm unable to get `@repeat_every()` to work with lifespan.

```py
from fastapi_utils.tasks import repeat_every
@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=60*30)  # every 30 minutes
def saveToReports(source:str=graphdir, dest:str="graphs"):
    """ save off summary graphs saved in source to reportserver if we have generated any """
    files = glob.glob(f"{source}/*.html")
    for i,file in enumerate(files):
        if i==0:
            log.debug("running task because we have files")
        reportsintra.upload(file, mypath=dest, justfile=True)
        os.unlink(file)
```

I've looked at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/ but I cant get it to work.
if I remove the `@app.on_event("startup")` it never runs.
leaving the `@repeat_every(seconds=60*30)` give an error:
`TypeError: lifespan() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

```py
@asynccontextmanager
#@repeat_every(seconds=60*30)  # do not work with lifespan
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    """ save off summary graphs saved in source to reportserver if we have generated any """
    source:str=graphdir
    dest:str="graphs"
    log.info("start background task")
    files = glob.glob(f"{source}/*.html")
    for i,file in enumerate(files):
        if i==0:
            log.debug("running task because we have files")
        reportsintra.upload(file, mypath=dest, justfile=True)
        os.unlink(file)
    yield

app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, redoc_url=None, lifespan=lifespan)
```

```bash
20240223101919.560|INFO|site-packages\uvicorn\lifespan\on.py:46|Waiting for application startup.
<lifespan runs once and do its things>
20240223101921.249|INFO|site-packages\uvicorn\lifespan\on.py:60|Application startup complete.
```

But how can I repeat it?, runs only once on startup.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Wouldn't moving the function to be repeated out to a separate function work? And then call that function from your lifespan function? That wouldn't change the signature of the lifespan function.

Comment: @Chris - option3 looks promising, I'm testing it, but `@repeat_every()` would have been shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chris and option3 of [FastApi background Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872276/fastapi-python-how-to-run-a-thread-in-the-background)

I got this to work:

```
async def uploadReports(source:str=graphdir, dest:str="graphs", interval:int=60):
    """ periodically upload generated html graphs to reports server """
    while True:
        log.info("run background task")
        files = glob.glob(f"{source}/*.html")
        for i,file in enumerate(files):
            if i==0:
                log.debug("running task because we have files")
            reportsintra.upload(file, mypath=dest, justfile=True)
            os.unlink(file)
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    """ background task starts at statrup """
    asyncio.create_task(uploadReports())
    yield

app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, redoc_url=None, lifespan=lifespan)
```

And from the log I see it repeats every 60sec:

```
20240223115725.778|INFO|main.py:30|run background task
20240223115825.780|INFO|main.py:30|run background task
20240223115925.803|INFO|main.py:30|run background task
20240223120025.796|INFO|main.py:30|run background task
20240223120125.816|INFO|main.py:30|run background task
20240223120225.836|INFO|main.py:30|run background task
```